# How to populate table from SQL data using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with headers; Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and Saturday. I have gathered user "shifts" from a database...

```
<tr>
      <th>Sunday</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
    </tr>
<?php $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE date = '" . $sunday . "' or date = '" . $monday . "' 
               or date = '" . $tuesday . "' or date = '" . $wednesday . "' 
               or date = '" . $thursday . "' or date = '" . $friday . "' 
               or date = '" . $saturday . "'"; 

      $result1 = $database->query($sql4);

      echo"<tr>";
      while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ 
             echo "<td>";
             echo $row4['name'];
             echo "</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>"
```

So there can be any amount of shifts per day, but dependant on what day the shift is on i need to place the shift under the correct table heading.

The shifts table has: shift_id, name, date, day

```
$resultsArray = array();
while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
     $weekDay = $row4['day'];
     $resultsArray[$weekDay][] = $row4['name'];
 }

for ($x = 0; $x <= count($resultsArray); $x++) {

 $sundayData = (!empty($resultsArray['Sunday'][$x]) ) ? $resultsArray['Sunday'][$x] : "";
 $mondayData = (!empty($resultsArray['Monday'][$x]) ) ? $resultsArray['Monday'][$x] : "";
 $tuesdayData = (!empty($resultsArray['Tuesday'][$x]) ) ? $resultsArray['Tuesday'][$x] : "";
 $wednesdayData = (!empty($resultsArray['Wednesday'][$x]) ) ? $resultsArray['Wednesday'][$x] : "";
 $thursdayData = (!empty($resultsArray['Thursday'][$x]) ) ? $resultsArray['Thursday'][$x] : "";
 $fridayData = (!empty($resultsArray['Friday'][$x]) ) ? $resultsArray['Friday'][$x] : "";
 $saturdayData = (!empty($resultsArray['Saturday'][$x]) ) ? $resultsArray['Saturday'][$x] : "";


 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$sundayData."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$mondayData."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$tuesdayData."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$wednesdayData."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$thursdayData."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$fridayData."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$saturdayData."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
```

}

?>

Comment: It will be difficult to help without seeing sample data from your table and a sample of how you want the output formatted, plus the query you are using in the variable `$sql4`.  Please edit your question to show some sample database rows and how the output is expected to look.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski added some detail, thanks

Comment: you've an obvious syntax error if that's your actual code

Comment: @Fred-ii- no my actual code is gathering the values from the database and printing out to the table as i have debugged, just wanted to make it as simple as possible to explain, thanks.

Comment: How are you expecting that while loop to execute inside a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer your question if I could see the exact structure of your data, but I'll give this a whirl anyway and hopefully you can see where i'm going with it.

What I would do is create an array and fill in the information as you go through the results. Once you have the new resulting array, build your table.

```
  $resultsArray = array();
  while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
         $weekDay = $row4['day'];
         $resultsArray[$weekDay][] = $row4['shift'];
  }
```

Now you have an array that contains all the shifts organized by day. Looping through this array will allow you to create your table the way you want.

This is untested so may have some mistakes in it, but here is an example...

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$resultsArray['Sunday'][$x]."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$resultsArray['Monday'][$x]."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$resultsArray['Tuesday'][$x]."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$resultsArray['Wednesday'][$x]."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$resultsArray['Thursday'][$x]."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$resultsArray['Friday'][$x]."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$resultsArray['Saturday'][$x]."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
```

Note :  Keep in mind you'll have to change this portion `$x <= 10` to fit your actual array size.

Comment: yeah thats the way i was thinking about going about it. I looped through the results and stored the results in each array related to the day, e.g. $sunday[], $monday[]. but the problem i have is how i actually print them under the correct heading? any thoughts?

Comment: would it be a case of print first index of sunday, move to monday and print first position etc etc and just do a check to see if the index position is not null, if null move on to next array until all arrays have been completed?

Comment: because they are in an array with the name of the heading you want, you just have to call the day you want when creating the table. For example when you create the first row and column... `echo $resultsArray['Sunday'][0];`

Comment: i kind of understand what you mean, is there any chance you could show a small code snippet to see an example?

Comment: @AaronC I added more detail to the answer for you

Comment: Yeah thats perfect i get where your going with it, thanks for the help i will implement this and let you know how it goes

Comment: Having an error about "undefined offset" which i am assuming is because there can be 4 shifts for sunday, 6 shifts for monday etc, therefore i would need to check to see if there is a shift otherwise echo a blank value in <td>?

Comment: @AaronC correct, my code was just meant as an example to get you going, not the final polished code. I would look to add something like this... `$thursData = ( !empty($resultsArray['Thursday'][$x]) ) ? $resultsArray['Thursday'][$x] : "";`

Comment: @ThrowBackDavid do i place this inside the table divs for each one? note quite sure that that code for $thursData does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108764/discussion-between-throwbackdewd-and-aaron-c).